# Concurrent update not showing

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, resultset

```
st = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

I'm using the above code to enable me to view changes in the database immediately (`st` is a Statement object and `connection` is a Connection object). But still insertions, updations and deletions are not reflected immediately. The are observed only after I re-run the program. Is there any way to refresh the resultset?

I'm not posting the entire code as it is very large. Please ask if I must produce any other part of the program.

I'm using MySQL for the backend.

Comment: You had hoped that the ResultSet you get back from a query is always updated to current database's data, right? That's not what it does. If someone else inserts data from other places, your ResultSet does not reflect that change. It only means you can use the ResultSet to modify the data you retrived (add/remove/etc) but if someone else (or other part of your code) modifies anything, this is not reflected.

Comment: Ok... So how can I refresh the ResultSet?

Comment: @bilesh.g By re-executing the statement.

Comment: I had tried that but for some reason it was showing an exception whenever I ran the program. Guess I'll just have to re-write the whole thing afresh.